# Replacing wires in Room from the 1980's

Tags: electrical, wiring, voltage, rewire

I have a couple questions on my rewire / remodel I am doing.

1. I rewired a ceiling with LED potlights.   I used 12/2 Romex.   I just noticed for some reason the room is running on 20Amp breakers.  Is this an issue?  Do I need to change it to a 15AMP?
2. The room is a large room.   They had for some reason made a switch which controlled at least one outlet, maybe more.   The wiring is not accessible via attic or wall, as there is no attic and it has wood panel walls.

The outlets were getting inconsistent Volt readings.

I unhooked the  switch wiring.

The closest outlet, which appeared to be controlled by the switch, had the switch wiring (B&W wires) and a second set of B&W wires.

I left what I felt was the Line wires in my new 20Amp GFCI.   GFCI continues to trip.   I put the volt meter on the White and ground (when hooked up to the GFCI) and get 125V.   I put the volt meter on the Black and ground (when hooked up to the GFCE) and I get 125V.

The two wires I believe to be the switch wires are unhooked (or I thought they were), both show 20V!

The two outlets down stream

Comment: Is the switch controlling the receptacles the same switch that controls the new LED lights? Or is it a separate switch?

Comment: Separate switch.   The switch that went to the outlets is on a different line and only controlled the switches.

Answer (score 1):

> LED potlights. I used 12/2 Romex. I just noticed for some reason the room is running on 20Amp breakers. Is this an issue?

For LED usage it's not a problem.

> They had for some reason made a switch which controlled at least one outlet

In this case, the switch(es) must be rated 20 Amp, and most of the cheapest ones are not.  When you have a 20 Amp circuit with one or more switched duplex receptacles, the usual 15 Amp switches are not allowed because anyone could plug in a couple of small appliances and draw way more than 15 Amps.

> volt meter on the White and ground (when hooked up to the GFCI) and get 125V.

So either hot and ground are reversed or your neutral is hot.  Either way, that outlet is wired wrong.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  On the switch for the Outlets, I took it out.   I can not figure out why I would be getting 20V on my black and 120V on my white on outlets after my GFCI.  The GFCI is a 20 Amp, and I have 125V showing on W and B on the GFCI.   The GFCI only has a line coming in and no load going out, as I disconnected the load, so I am guessing whoever wired it has each outlet pigtailed?   Very odd wiring.

Comment: The 20v may be voltage induced magnetically from nearby wires. If so, it has virtually no amperage behind it and really doesn't matter; it is only showing up because there's no load on that wire and will vanish when something is actually turned on. See past questions about low voltage found on neutral.